# Aws s3 object permission changing in php is not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-permissions

I looking for changing the permission of object in amazon aws s3. I have tried several times. But it not working. My file permission is private and i want to change as public. My code is given below.

1.php

```
include('s3_config.php');

$uri = '147936871180.jpg';  

if (($acp = S3::getAccessControlPolicy($bucket, $uri)) !== false) {


    // Here you would modify the $acp array...
    // For example, grant access to the S3 LogDelivery system:

    $acp["acl"][] = array(
        "type" => "Group", "uri" => "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers", "permission" => "READ_ACP"
    );

    $acp["acl"][] = array(
        "type" => "Group", "uri" => "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers", "permission" => "WRITE_ACP"
    );
    // Then update the policy using the modified $acp array:
    if (S3::setAccessControlPolicy($bucket, $uri, $acp)) {
        echo "Policy updated";
    }
}


?>
```

s3_config.php

```
<?php
// Bucket Name
$bucket="testapp1541";
if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');
//AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'AKIAJJJJJJJJJJGFNVPA');
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', '8CiFyiqc7SguQq11111t2LPV289CyuCaMF2Uq');
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
$s3->putBucket($bucket, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ_WRITE);
?>
```

But it shows the output is

Warning: S3::putBucket(testapp541): [BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou] Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it. in D:\xampp\htdocs\work\aws\s1\S3.php on line 375
Policy updated

But it not change the permission as public.

How to change permission as public. Please help me.